Where can I buy these "end caps" for hanging blinds?
Looking to make a repair for a blind in the UK, South West.
Rather than replacing the whole blind, I'd like to replace just the end caps which are screwed onto the wall. When I've been to ordinary (e.g. high street) shops I can only find full blind sets and not just the end pieces. Illustrated in images!



Very grateful for any advice!

What exactly is wrong with the existing ones?

The gold-coloured "pin" that extends perpendicular to the white base hooks under the end of the blind to hold it steady. These have broken on both sides.

Usually it's necessary to contact the manufacturer to get replacement parts.  The store should have that info.  If not, you can take a peek at the warranty for contact info.
